# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target'),

Tags: react-redux

My problem is that how do i access 'handleInputChange', because  i cant write 'handleInputChange' function outside the useEffect hook since it is performing a sideeffect. I would love it if someone can help me out with this situation.

```
1.  const [values, setValue] = useState({});
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

   let handleInputChange
    useEffect(()=>{
        handleInputChange = (e) =>{
        setValue(
            {
                values: { ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
            }, 
            () => {
            dispatch({
            type: "SET_FORMVALUES",
            payload: values
            })
        }
    )}
    handleInputChange();
    },[dispatch])

<TextField id="outlined-basic" label="First Name" variant="outlined"
                        name="firstName"
                        className='app__input'
                        placeholder='First Name'
                        type="text"
                        value={values['firstName']}
                        onChange = {handleInputChange} />

//Reducer.js

const initialState = {
  formValues: {},
  message: ""
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_FORMVALUES":
      console.log("--- Changing form data ---");
      return {
        ...state,
        formValues: action.payload
      };
    case "SUBMIT_FORM":
      return {
        ...state,
        message: "Form submitted!!"
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: You tagged this with `react-redux`, and I see you're using `useDispatch()`, but it appears you may be mixing default React state concepts with react-redux concepts. Do you have a redux store and reducers configured? If so, can you share the relevant reducer code?

Comment: I have added the reducer.js code and yes, I have configured the redux store.

Comment: It is performing the "SUBMIT_FORM" action type which is just a normal function.

Comment: Do you have @reduxjs/toolkit installed in your project, or just redux and react-redux?

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you want or expect to happen with this code? It seems like when the text input changes, and `handleInputChange` is fired, two different states are updated, and then the value of the text input is set based on one of those states. It looks circular and I can't tell what your intention is. Is there any other relevant code not included here?

Comment: just redux and react-redux, yes when i try to change the text input the 'handleInputChange' gets fired and needs to update the state.

Comment: All i am trying to do is a form validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need the core React `useState` hook, because you are using React Redux. This is actually creating a second state local to your component. Instead, use the centralized Redux store you've configured and React-Redux hooks. As long as you have [wrapped your app in a context provider](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#provide-the-redux-store-to-react) and passed your store to it, you can use `useDispatch` to update state and `useSelector` to retrieve state and subscribe to changes.

Second, you don't need `useEffect`, as you are just updating state.

Here's an example:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function App() {
    const formValues = useSelector((state) => state.formValues);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleInputChange = (name, value) => {
        dispatch(
            {
                type: "SET_FORMVALUES", 
                payload: {
                    ...formValues,
                    [name]: value
                }
            }
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" onChange={ (e) => handleInputChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)} />
            <span>{formValues["FirstName"]}</ span>
            <input type="text" name="LastName" onChange={ (e) => handleInputChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)} />
            <span>{formValues["LastName"]}</ span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Much of this is probably not directly related to the error in the question title, but simplifying your code should help you debug more easily. That error may have been simply because you didn't explicitly pass the event in your onChange handler. I.e. `onChange = {handleInputChange}` vs. `onChange = {(e) => handleInputChange(e)}`

Comment: Yes, I just ignored that redux store is "single source of truth", Thank you so much for the help